# Change IIS Application address

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I need to know if Its possible to change my web site address.

I have IIS application locate under `Default Web Site\MyApp` And the address is:

```
http:/localhost/myapp
```

And I want to change the address to

```
http://localhost
```

Without the `/myapp` Its possible to do that **without to move the application directory**?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can change the Physical path of your Default Website.

Right-Click "Default Web Site" --> Manage Website --> Advanced Settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your web.config file or another way is, you can configure default document in IIS. Here is the link that might help :
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument